# Classifcation of $p$-groups with cyclic subgroup of index $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, group-cohomology, p-groups

I am trying to read the Classification of p-Groups with cyclic subgroup of index p done in Cohomology of Groups by Brown. He starts his proof by construction the exact sequence, $0→\mathbb{Z}_q→G→H→0$ ,he then says that the action of $H$ on $\mathbb{Z}_q$ is given by an embedding $H$ in  $\mathbb{Z}_q$*, where $\mathbb{Z}_q^*$ is the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}_q$, and i dont quite see why this statement is true.

New edit: 
I didnt wanna make a new question for this since its in the same proof , but can anyone enlighted me on why the image of the embedding of $H$ in the group of units is $\{1+b:b \in p^{n-1}\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}\}$?

Comment: I seem to recall this was asked already, but I can't find it.

Comment: @MattSamuel The same user asked a very similar question a few minutes ago, with the same title, then asking why $G$ must be abelian if $H$ acts trivially on $\Bbb{Z}_q$. Or do you recall another question?

Comment: @Servaes It had the same title at the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subgroup $\Bbb{Z}/q\Bbb{Z}$ is normal in $G$, so the action of $H$ induces an automorphism of $\Bbb{Z}/q\Bbb{Z}$. Every automorphism of $\Bbb{Z}/q\Bbb{Z}$ is given by multiplication by some invertible element in $\Bbb{Z}/q\Bbb{Z}$. This yields an embedding of $H$ in $(\Bbb{Z}/q\Bbb{Z})^{\times}$ **if and only if** the action of $H$ on  $\Bbb{Z}/q\Bbb{Z}$ is nontrivial, because $H\cong\Bbb{Z}/p\Bbb{Z}$.

Of course, if the action of $H$ on  $\Bbb{Z}/q\Bbb{Z}$ is trivial then  $\Bbb{Z}/q\Bbb{Z}$ is a central subgroup giving a cyclic quotient, and so $G$ is abelian. (This answers your question from a few minutes ago, now deleted).

Comment: @Something Is there something suddenly wrong with the answer?